# faster way to run a for loop for a very large dataframe list

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, for-loop

I am using two for loops inside each other to calculate a value using combinations of elements in a dataframe list. the list consists of large number of dataframes and using two for loops takes considerable amount of time.

Is there a way i can do the operation faster?

the functions I refer with dummy names are the ones where I calculate the results.

My code looks like this:

```
 conf_list = []

 for tr in range(len(trajectories)):
     df_1 = trajectories[tr]

     if len(df_1) == 0:
        continue
   
     for tt in range(len(trajectories)):
         df_2 = trajectories[tt]

         if len(df_2) == 0:
            continue

         if df_1.equals(df_2) or df_1['time'].iloc[0] > df_2['time'].iloc[-1] or df_2['time'].iloc[0] > df_1['time'].iloc[-1]:
            continue

         df_temp = cartesian_product_basic(df_1,df_2)
    
         flg, df_temp = another_function(df_temp)
    
         if flg == 0:
             continue

         flg_h = some_other_function(df_temp)
    
         if flg_h == 1:
            conf_list.append(1)
```

My input list consist of around 5000 dataframes looking like (having several hundreds of rows)

| id | x | y | z | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 7 | 2 | 5 |

and what i do is I get the cartesian product with combinations of two dataframes and for each couple I calculate another value 'c'. If this value c meets a condition then I add an element to my c_list so that I can get the final number of couples meeting the requirement.

For further info;

a_function(df_1, df_2) is a function getting the cartesian product of two dataframes.

another_function looks like this:

```
  def another_function(df_temp):
      df_temp['z_dif'] =      nwh((df_temp['time_x'] == df_temp['time_y'])
                                          , abs(df_temp['z_x']-  df_temp['z_y']) , np.nan)

      df_temp = df_temp.dropna() 

      df_temp['vert_conf'] = nwh((df_temp['z_dif'] >= 1000)
                                          , np.nan , 1)
      df_temp = df_temp.dropna() 

      if len(df_temp) == 0:
       flg = 0
      else:
       flg = 1
    
      return flg, df_temp
```

and some_other_function looks like this:

```
  def some_other_function(df_temp):
      df_temp['x_dif'] =   df_temp['x_x']*df_temp['x_y']
      df_temp['y_dif'] = df_temp['y_x']*df_temp['y_y']
      df_temp['hor_dif'] = hypot(df_temp['x_dif'], df_temp['y_dif'])

      df_temp['conf'] = np.where((df_temp['hor_dif']<=5)
                                          , 1 , np.nan)
      if df_temp['conf'].sum()>0:
         flg_h = 1
    
     return flg_h
```

Comment: Please include sample input and output dfs. This way it's much easier to see what you want to do than eyeballing your code.

Comment: read doc about `enumerate`, place `if len(df_1) == 0` outside loop `for tt`, sort your dataframes based on `time`, and every `n^2` algorithm is slow on big numbers

Comment: how fast is the algorithm if you disable all the `d_temp` stuff ( the calculations you **have** to do), is it finding what to calculate or doing the actual calculation that takes the time

Comment: when i comment out the calculation itself doing the 100 outer loops takes around 10 seconds, with the current code it took me half an hour. i guess its the calculation itself..

Comment: The algorithm might be improved but this is impossible to know without the code of `a_function` and `another_function` or at least some information about them. Providing a **minimal reproducible example** help a lot. For example if `a_function(df_1,df_2)` is symmetric, then you can skip half the computations. If it is idempotent, then much more calls can be avoided. The data type matters a lot too for vectorization.

Comment: I edited the question to provide more information

Answer (score 1):

The following are the way to make your code run faster:

- Instead of `for-loop` use list comprehension.
- use built-in functions like `map`, `filter`, sum ect, this would make your code faster.
- Do not use '.' or dot operants, for example

```
Import datetime
A=datetime.datetime.now() #dont use this 
From datetime.datetime import now as timenow
A=timenow()# use this
```

- Use c/c++ based operation libraries like numpy.
- Don't convert datatypes unnecessarily.
- in infinite loops, use **1** instead of "`True`"
- Use built-in Libraries.
- if the data would not change, convert it to a tuple
- Use String Concatenation
- Use Multiple Assignments
- Use Generators
- When using `if-else` to check a Boolean value, avoid using assignment operator.

```
# Instead of Below approach
if a==1:
    print('a is 1')
else:
    print('a is 0')

# Try this approach 
if a:
    print('a is 1')
else:
    print('a is 0')

# This would help as a portion of time is reduce which was used in check the 2 values.
```

Usefull references:

- [Speeding up Python Code: Fast Filtering and Slow Loops](https://towardsdatascience.com/speeding-up-python-code-fast-filtering-and-slow-loops-8e11a09a9c2f)
- [Speed Up Python Code](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/speed-up-python-code/)