# How to make a for loop run faster on a large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, for-loop

I have a dataframe which has 900k records and need to perform the below python logic on it.
The python code works fine on a smaller dataframe but doesnt work on a large dataframe.

For loop in the code is the problem.

How can i make the for loop run faster. It takes 90 seconds for 1000 rows and runs forever when the dataframe crosses 10000 rows.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data - Copy.csv')
df[["Treat_Date"]] = df[["Treat_Date"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df

## create min date for each key

df1 = df.groupby(['key'])['Treat_Date'].min().reset_index()
df1 = df.merge(df1)
df2 = df.merge(df1, how='inner', on=['key'])

##counter for each key to identify the first instance

df2['counter'] = df2.groupby(['key']).cumcount()+1
df2

##=IF(B3<=F2+90,F2,B3)  - this is the excel logic


##replicating excel logic on python

df1_grouped = df2.groupby('key')
df1_grouped

# iterate over each key
for group_name, df_group in df1_grouped:

    for ind, row in df2.iterrows():
        if row['counter'] == 1 : 
            df2.loc[ind,"Test"] = row['Treat_Date_y']
        if row['counter'] != 1 : 
             if row['Treat_Date_x'] <= df2.loc[ind-1,"Test"]  + pd.Timedelta(days=90) :
                df2.loc[ind,"Test"] = df2.loc[ind-1,"Test"] 
             else:
                df2.loc[ind,"Test"] = row['Treat_Date_x']

##create counter for each key and window combination
## all 1's are legit and all the 2 and more are recoverable

df3 = df2.copy()
df3['counter_2'] = df3.groupby(['key','Test']).cumcount()+1
df3
```

Data used :

```
key Treat_Date
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  5/19/2019
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  6/20/2019
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  7/29/2019
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  9/3/2019
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  10/13/2019
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  12/29/2020
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  2/3/2021
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  3/13/2021
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  4/18/2021
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  5/24/2021
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  7/5/2021
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  8/19/2021
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  9/22/2021
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  10/27/2021
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  12/8/2021
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  7/5/2022
6262452_Krish's Medical Center  7/30/2022
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  5/19/2019
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  6/20/2019
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  7/29/2019
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  9/3/2019
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  10/13/2019
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  12/29/2020
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  2/3/2021
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  3/13/2021
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  4/18/2021
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  5/24/2021
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  7/5/2021
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  8/19/2021
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  9/22/2021
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  10/27/2021
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  12/8/2021
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  7/5/2022
6262452_Mithuns Medical Center  7/30/2022
```

I have read that apply method is a faster way to approach this issue. But I am not sure how to covert this for loop to an apply method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [faster way to run a for loop for a very large dataframe list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71276796/faster-way-to-run-a-for-loop-for-a-very-large-dataframe-list)

Comment: In general, for-loop on dataframe rows are slow because that's not how dataframes are supposed to be used.
You should specify operations on columns (which apply on each rows) so that pandas, behind the scene, parallelize the operations for you

Comment: Could you please describe the logic of what you are trying to accomplish? I fear the code provided is much more complex than it needs to be (based on the comment "`=IF(B3<=F2+90,F2,B3)` - this is the excel logic"). It's a bit of detective work from the code.

Comment: @PierreD Your understanding of the problem is correct.

Comment: FYI, I added a couple of approaches using `numba`. Best speed so far is 234ms for 1 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: IIUC, this can not be expressed in a fully vectorized fashion. But a "semi-vectorized" algorithm below achieves **~7s for 1 million rows**. Further efforts using `numba` get us to between **234 ms to 670 ms for 1 million rows**.

---

#### Part 1: using `numpy`

Based on the comment in the code: "`=IF(B3<=F2+90,F2,B3) - this is the excel logic`", and on the result obtained by running your code on the data sample you provide, I think the logic that you want to implement is:

> *Within each `key` group, look for a subgroup of dates within 90 days past the first `Treat_Date`; then look for the next subgroup of dates within the first `Treat_Date` outside the first subgroup, and so forth.*

If that interpretation is correct, then it is one of the very few operations that cannot be vectorized with Numpy or Pandas (at least to my knowledge and as of this writing). It is a kind of operation where there is a serial dependency in the calculation, along with decision criteria that can not be established beforehand, but only through the serial calculation.

Another classic problem in that category is: "cumulative sum with reset to 0 if the cumulative sum passes some threshold".

The two are actually related, as we will see. Let us write something that still contains loops, but is partially vectorized:

```py
import numpy as np

def cumsum_reset(a, upto):
    c = a.cumsum()
    while True:
        i = np.argmax(c > upto)
        if c[i] <= upto: break
        c[i:] -= c[i]
    return c

>>> cumsum_reset(np.repeat(1, 10), upto=4)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0])

>>> cumsum_reset(np.repeat(1, 10), upto=3.5)
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2])
```

Application to your problem:

```py
def extend_upto(s, upto):
    """
    repeat the first value until the difference
    reaches upto; when it exceeds it, start with the
    next value; and so on...
    """
    if isinstance(s, pd.Series):
        s = s.values
    return s - cumsum_reset(np.diff(np.r_[s[0], s]), upto)

>>> np.c_[(a := np.arange(10)), extend_upto(a, upto=3)].T
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8]])

>>> np.c_[(a := np.arange(10)), extend_upto(a, upto=2.5)].T
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 9]])
```

This can be used to produce the date grouping as desired:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.date_range('2000', periods=5, freq='45D'),
    columns=['t']
)

>>> df.assign(dategroup=extend_upto(df['t'], pd.Timedelta('90 days')))
           t  dategroup
0 2000-01-01 2000-01-01
1 2000-02-15 2000-01-01
2 2000-03-31 2000-01-01
3 2000-05-15 2000-05-15
4 2000-06-29 2000-05-15
```

One last bit is to also establish a counter within each group of `key, Test` where `Test` is the "extended date upto 90 days". Putting it all together:

```py
def proc(df):
    dfnew = df.assign(
        Test=df.groupby('key')['Treat_Date'].transform(
            extend_upto, upto=pd.Timedelta('90 days')))
    dfnew['counter'] = dfnew.groupby(['key', 'Test']).cumcount() + 1
    return dfnew
```

Application:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(my_filename, parse_dates=['Treat_Date'])

dfnew = proc(df)
```

On your data sample:

```py
>>> dfnew
                               key Treat_Date       Test  counter
0   6262452_Krish's Medical Center 2019-05-19 2019-05-19        1
1   6262452_Krish's Medical Center 2019-06-20 2019-05-19        2
2   6262452_Krish's Medical Center 2019-07-29 2019-05-19        3
3   6262452_Krish's Medical Center 2019-09-03 2019-09-03        1
4   6262452_Krish's Medical Center 2019-10-13 2019-09-03        2
...
29  6262452_Mithuns Medical Center 2021-09-22 2021-08-19        2
30  6262452_Mithuns Medical Center 2021-10-27 2021-08-19        3
31  6262452_Mithuns Medical Center 2021-12-08 2021-12-08        1
32  6262452_Mithuns Medical Center 2022-07-05 2022-07-05        1
33  6262452_Mithuns Medical Center 2022-07-30 2022-07-05        2
```

Which is identical to what your code produces (for columns `Test` and `counter_2` -- here renamed `counter`), but much faster (see speed test below).

#### Part 2: using `numba` in `groupby().transform()`

This uses the ability of certain functions of `groupby` such as `transform()` and `apply()` to use [Numba (JIT compilation)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#numba-jit-compilation) functions. In a way, the calculation can then be expressed in a more "naive" way, closer to the original Excel expression (look at the `extend_upto()` version inside of `nb_proc()`). However, due to some existing limitations, it is a bit less flexible: type-awareness is less straightforward, and we cannot currently use `kwargs` together with the `'numba'` engine in `groupby.transform()`. See e.g., [numba#2916](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2916). But with a little bit of care, we can still do it and gain a ~10x speedup:

```py
# numba version
from numba import njit


def nb_proc(df, upto=pd.Timedelta('90 days')):
    upto_value = upto.value

    @njit
    def extend_upto(values, index):
        nonlocal upto_value
        b = values
        f = np.empty_like(b)
        n = len(f)
        # IF(B3<=F2+90,F2,B3)
        f[0] = b[0]
        for i in range(1, n):
            f[i] = f[i-1] if b[i] <= f[i-1] + upto_value else b[i]
        return f

    dfnew = df.assign(
        Test=pd.to_datetime(
            df.assign(z=df['Treat_Date'].astype(int))
            .groupby('key')['z']
            .transform(extend_upto, engine='numba')
        )
    )
    dfnew['counter'] = dfnew.groupby(['key', 'Test']).cumcount() + 1

    return dfnew
```

#### Part 3: using only `numba`

Yet another ~3x speedup is to do away with `groupby` and `transform` altogether. Instead, we first require the data to be sorted by `key, Treat_Date` (if we have to do it ourselves, then it reduces the additional speedup to only about 30%). The logic is: if the `key` changes or the date is beyond 90 days of the first date, then a new subgroup needs to be started:

```py
# numba only (no groupby, tranform, ...)
def nbo_proc(df, upto=pd.Timedelta('90 days')):
    
    @njit
    def process(same_key, date, upto):
        out_date = np.empty_like(date)
        counter = np.empty_like(date, dtype=np.int64)
        
        out_date[0] = date[0]
        k = 1
        counter[0] = k
        for i in range(1, len(date)):
            if same_key[i] and date[i] <= out_date[i-1] + upto:
                # keep propagating
                out_date[i] = out_date[i-1]
                k += 1
            else:
                # new key group or date sub-group
                out_date[i] = date[i]
                k = 1
            counter[i] = k

        return out_date, counter

    out_date, counter = process(
        (df['key'] == df['key'].shift()).to_numpy(),
        df['Treat_Date'].to_numpy().astype(int),
        upto=upto.value,
    )
    dfnew = df.assign(
        Test=pd.to_datetime(out_date),
        counter=counter,
    )
    return dfnew
```

#### Speed

We now benchmark the solutions above. To do so, we create a synthetic, 1-million row DataFrame. By construction, it is already sorted by `key, Treat_Date`:

```py
n = 1_000_000
pergroup = 100
ngroups = n // pergroup

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randint(1, 100, pergroup).cumsum(),
        columns=['Treat_Date']
    ).assign(key=f'group {i:06d}')
    for i in range(ngroups)
]).reset_index(drop=True)[['key', 'Treat_Date']]
df['Treat_Date'] = pd.Timestamp('2000') + df['Treat_Date'] * pd.Timedelta('1 day')
```

First and last five rows:

```py
>>> df.head(5)
            key Treat_Date
0  group 000000 2000-02-15
1  group 000000 2000-04-03
2  group 000000 2000-06-07
3  group 000000 2000-08-14
4  group 000000 2000-10-21

>>> df.tail(5)
                 key Treat_Date
999995  group 009999 2013-04-20
999996  group 009999 2013-05-31
999997  group 009999 2013-09-01
999998  group 009999 2013-11-02
999999  group 009999 2013-11-21
```

Correctness (and initial compilation for `@njit` functions):

```py
>>> proc(df).equals(nb_proc(df))
True

>>> nb_proc(df).equals(nbo_proc(df))
True
```

Speed measurements:

```py
%timeit proc(df)
6.8 s ± 37.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit nb_proc(df)
670 ms ± 1.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit nbo_proc(df)
234 ms ± 888 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you, Pierre, for your effort. Really appreciate this. Though the excel logic was simple and easy to understand. I had a feel that this was more complicated when developing it on Python. I will try these steps.

Comment: It is only complicated when trying to do it in a vectorized way (or close to vectorized). A simple loop would be simpler, but much too slow. Another approach would be to use `numba`: simple loops made fast through just-in-time compilation. When I have more time I'll perhaps revisit this answer in that direction.